# How to deprecate a C pre-processor macro in GCC?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, macros, deprecated

I know how to use `__attribute__((deprecated))` or `[[deprecated]]` to deprecate a function like this:

```
int old_fn() __attribute__ ((deprecated));
[[deprecated]] int old_fn2();
```

But how to deprecate a Macro like this:

```
#define OLD_MACRO 1
```

Answer (score 17):

Nice, elegant solution, however depending on C99 being enabled (works with gcc 4.8.2 or later, not tested on earlier versions):

```
#define DEPRECATED_MACRO1 _Pragma ("GCC warning \"'DEPRECATED_MACRO1' macro is deprecated\"") 7
#define DEPRECATED_MACRO2(...) _Pragma ("GCC warning \"'DEPRECATED_MACRO2' macro is deprecated\"") printf(__VA_ARGS__)

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    int n = DEPRECATED_MACRO1;
    DEPRECATED_MACRO2("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work wth gcc 4.3.3. Nice option though.

Comment: @mjs According to [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/c99status.html), `_Pragma` should have been supported since gcc 3.0 (full C99 support since gcc 4.5). You might have to enable C99 explicitly with `-std=c99` previously to 4.5 (possibly even later, don't really know when c99 got standard for gcc...) to make that work.

Comment: @Aconcagua I think _Pragma was recognised, it just didn't understand the content. But i might be wrong.

Comment: @mjs To see if it understands the content, try `#pragma GCC warning "'DEPRECATED_MACRO1' macro is deprecated"`. This is what the `_Pragma` stuff is equivalent to...

Answer (score 9):

I think the best you can do is something like this:

```
#ifdef USE_DEPRECATED_MACROS
#warning using deprecated macros
#define OLD_MACRO 1
...
#endif
```

This way you force the user to e.g. add -DUSE_DEPRECATED_MACROS to their compiler options and they get a warning.

Comment: As a matter of taste, I would prefer to have the user `#define USE_DEPRECATED_MACROS 1` in their source before the `#include` rather than putting the flag in through the command line... but really, same result either way; they have to know what they're doing, and can back it out when possible (and lose the warning thereby). Good call!

Comment: I'd do it the other way around: `#ifndef NO_DEPRECATED_MACROS`. That way, you issue the warning while maintaining source-compatibility for clients of your header file. The user can then add `NO_DEPRECATED_MACROS` to get rid of the warning, rather than his build breaking when he takes the new header file, and him having to read the release notes to find out why OLD_MACRO is gone. Of course if the user uses `-Werror` it all amounts to the same thing, but if he doesn't then maybe that's precisely because he doesn't want his build falling over because you're tinkering with warnings ;-)

Comment: This wouldn't tell the user WHICH deprecated macro is being used / which ones he should replace by what etc.

Answer (score 7):

You could make sure that these macros would expand to something that would include a expression that would trigger the `__attribute__((deprecated))` warning.

For function-like macros this is pretty easy (especially with the comma operator), but for constant defines or nonstandard macros this may be more complicated, since the context in which these expand is different.
I think you could do:

```
#define DEPRECATE(name) static inline void __attribute__((deprecated)) deprecate_ ## name (void) { ; }
...
#define MAX(x, y) (DEPRECATE(MAX), x>y?x:y)
// yeah, yeah, it repeats args in the body, but it's just an example
```

For a constant define you probably want to assume that the body has to evaluate without having to generate code, such as outside of a function body, in the targets of a switch/case, or as the initial value of a static variable within a function.

This is tricky, but you may be able to do it for many things.

I wish that C had a `__builtin_warn(const char *)` that would work at the compiler level (not-preprocessor) and make things like this easier.

For constant defines you can do:

```
#define THREE (DEPRICATED(THREE),3)
```

Comment: And indeed if you had that macro you would need to deprecate it.

Comment: @Joshua: In the next release of the software `THREE` won't be defined, but in the version after that, `#define THREE (4)`.

Comment: "_Implicit declaration of function 'DEPRICATED' is invalid in C99_". And if I use `DEPRECATE`, I get "_Expected expression_".

Answer (score 0):

Since Macros are not part of the compiler (they are a pre-processor function), there is no clean way of doing this. At best, place your deprecated macros in a new header file filled with #warnings. This will of course break existing code, but its one way to guarantee drawing attention to the deprecation.