# Print a deprecation warning when using a macro in a #if statement

Tags: c, preprocessor, pragma

I want to deprecate a macro in such a way that it will print a nice warning even if used inside of a `#if` statement.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29297970/2404152) is very nearly what I want, but it throws an error when the macro is accessed from within a `#if` statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEPRECATED_CONSTANT _Pragma ("GCC warning \"Deprecated constant!\"") 0
#define DEPRECATED_FUNCTION(...) _Pragma ("GCC warning \"Deprecated function!\"") printf(__VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
    // Prints a warning (good)
    int n = DEPRECATED_CONSTANT;

    // Prints a warning (good)
    DEPRECATED_FUNCTION("%d\n", n);

// Throws an error (bad)
#if DEPRECATED_CONSTANT
    return 1;
#else
    return 2;
#endif
}
```

The error is:

```
error: missing binary operator before token "("
```

Bonus points if you can find me a cross-platform compatible solution!

**EDIT**

I'm trying to handle a breaking change in a library gracefully - I want users to have a nice, clear warning (or error) whenever they use an old macro, so it will be clear that they need to migrate their code to using the new macro. These pragma solutions only work if the value of that constant is used in code, not if the value is accessed in a preprocessor directive.

According to the answers provided below, it seems like there's not a solution to this problem (except possibly when using clang?). Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Can you add context. What do you want to test by writing `#if DEPRECATED_CONSTANT` ? You want to test if the macro is define ?

Comment: I want to print a deprecation warning whenever the macro is used in any way.

Comment: I'm assuming your use case prevents you from using `#ifdef`?

Comment: @Stargateur I think he wants to check the constant (if it is true).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to deprecate a macro in such a way that it will print a nice
>   warning even if used inside of a #if statement.

I was going to suggest the comma operator, but that doesn't seem to work because the _Pragma macro probably yields no real code.  Also, gcc, at least, explicitly says you can't do what you suggested with _Pragma():

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html

> The standard is unclear on where a _Pragma operator can appear. **The
>   preprocessor does not accept it within a preprocessing conditional
>   directive like ‘#if’.** To be safe, you are probably best keeping it out
>   of directives other than ‘#define’, and putting it on a line of its
>   own.

PS - clang 8.1.0 didn't error on your program and gave the warnings you want ...

Answer (score 1):

As @jschultz410 mentions, what you are trying to do is explicitly forbidden in gcc (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html).

Nested macros seem appropriate for such a use case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEPRECATED_CONSTANT_VALUE 0
#define DEPRECATED_CONSTANT _Pragma ("GCC warning \"Deprecated constant!\"") DEPRECATED_CONSTANT_VALUE
#define DEPRECATED_FUNCTION(...) _Pragma ("GCC warning \"Deprecated function!\"") printf(__VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
    // Prints a warning (good)
    int n = DEPRECATED_CONSTANT;

    // Prints a warning (good)
    DEPRECATED_FUNCTION("%d\n", n);

// Throws an error (bad)
#if DEPRECATED_CONSTANT_VALUE
    return 1;
#else
    return 2;
#endif
}
```

Yes, this is kind of gross, but in the land of preprocessor logic we're already giving up on any kind of design elegance in the first place. At least this way the macro interface is maintained in non-preprocessor code. (Yes, this would not print the preprocessor warning in the `#if` statement, but unfortunately that's not possible with gcc).