# What is the best way to mark macro as deprecated?

Tags: c

I know how to mark enums/functions as deprecated by using
`__attribute__ ((deprecated))`. But how can I mark constant macro
as deprecated?

```
#define MACRO1 4 //This is deprecated macro
```

Comment: Is the macro used in any constant expression contexts? You know that `__attribute__((deprecated))` works only with gcc (and similar) compilers.

Comment: Related, if a bit old:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681259/how-to-deprecate-a-macro-in-gcc  I'm of the opinion that it's not really a duplicate as that asks for GCC-specific answers.  This question asks for more general answers.  Given the elapsed time, there's a distinct chance for newer, better answers here.

Comment: @KamilCuk, The macro is used in the code but not in other macros.
I mean that there is no other macros that depend on this macro.

Comment: I ask if the macro is used  like `struct A { char field : MACRO1; }` or `static char arr[MACRO1];`, as a constant expression.

Comment: Very good question indeed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deprecate a macro in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681259/how-to-deprecate-a-macro-in-gcc)

Answer (score 4):

## GCC (and possibly others)

### `__attribute__((deprecated))`

For your particular example with just a constant expression, you can use this:

Change

```
#define X (4)
```

to

```
#define X_old (4)
```

and then add

```
const int dep __attribute__((deprecated)) = 0;
#define X ((void)dep, X_old)
```

Addition also works:

```
#define X (X_old + dep)
```

For a procedure macro you can do this:

```
#define P_old do { ... } while(0)
#define P do { (void)dep; P_old; } while(0)
```

The only function of `(void)` is to suppress warnings. Thanks Kevin.

### `#pragma message`

Another solution is to put all deprecated macros in a separate header file and use `pragma`. You could combine this with `#ifdef` and such:

```
#pragma message ("This header contains deprecated macros")
```

## All compilers

### Unreferenced label

Use an unreferenced label:

```
#define P_old do { ... } while(0)
#define P do { P_IS_DEPRECATED: P_old; } while(0)
```

This does not work for constant expression macros and requires you to compile with `-Wall` to get a warning. Will trigger error if used more than once.

### Unused variable:

```
#define P_old do { ... } while(0)
#define P do { int P_IS_DEPRECATED; P_old; } while(0)
```

Does not work on constant expressions either. Also requires `-Wall` but can be used more than once.

## Sidenote

Remember to encapsulate constant expression macros in parentheses. The macro `#define X 2+3` would make an expression like `2*X` to expand to `2*2+3` instead of `2*(2+3)`.

Comment: You could add a `(void)dep;` to get rid of the unused value warning.

Comment: @Kevin Done. Thanks.

Comment: `Some C++ compilers have problems with expanding do-while ininline functions` O, wow. Do you have any C++ compilers in mind? Any experience with that?

Comment: @KamilCuk Nope. Seltzer tried to edit, but I edited at the same time. I have included the source for that statement.

Comment: @KamilCuk: the site says *historically some C++ compilers have refused to inline-expand any function containing a loop.* in reference to the use of the `do { multiple statements } while(0)` trick to encapsulate multiple statements as a single statement. This remark is obsolete and irrelevant, anybody still using such compilers has more pressing problems to deal with and the rest of us should not care, especially for a question tagged as **c**.

Comment: @chqrlie So you think I should delete it?

Comment: @klutt: yes, I think so. It is unrelated to the OP's question.

Comment: Parens are not necessary when the expansion is a single token (but good advice for other macro definitions, I'm sure).

Comment: This solution is nice, but doesn't work if you need the macro value to be valid for use in preprocessor expressions (changing `(void)dep` to `(void)+dep` would at least make it valid, but would not give a warning in that context) and doesn't make it an integer constant expression you can use in contexts that require one.

Comment: @TobySpeight That's true, but they never do any harm so it's good practice to always use them.

Comment: @R.. I tried `#define Y (X+X)` and then I printed `2*Y` and it gave the desired result.

Comment: @klutt: `#if X == 1`